# Qual é a melhor forma de sair de uma aplicação em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

A forma mais comum é sair com um `return` no `Main()`. Mas eu vi que existem o [`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) e o [`Application.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx).

Quando devemos usar cada um?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A melhor forma é o `return` no `Main()`. É o menos traumático.

Mas se tiver algum motivo para sair antes o [`Environment.Exit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pode ser usado em qualquer ponto da aplicação sem maiores problemas. Note que isso pode pular alguma finalização desejada que só ocorreria se saísse no `Main()`, mas aí é algo específico da sua aplicação e ocorre em raros casos (veja documentação). Então se pretende fazer sair fora do `Main()`, seja com um *exit* explícito ou por uma exceção, o ideal é que não tenha dependências para sair ou que o que precise ser feito seja sempre chamado antes de uma saída fora do `Main()`. Em geral deve criar uma função que deve ser chamada antes de sair para executar o que precisa ser sempre executado antes da saída. Só cuidado para não gerar erros nesse ponto.

Deve-se evitar sair por exceção, mas se for erro de programação a única coisa a se fazer é encerrar a aplicação mesmo. Se deixar a exceção sem tratamento e for um erro de programação a saída será muito parecida com a saída pelo `return` no `Main()` já que a exceção provoca o *stack unwinding*.

O [`Application.Exit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) faz parte do  Windows Forms, pode ver o *namespace* que ele está. Ele faz o mesmo que a forma anterior, porém ele faz o encerramento correto dos formulários encerrando o *message loop* do sistema de janelas do sistema operacional, muito provavelmente o Windows.

Seria bom dar uma olhada no [`Environment.FailFast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que serve para alguns casos onde a saída precisa ser imediata.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).